# test MacOSX application binary on PPC MacOSX

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, powerpc

I want to add support for PPC to my MacOSX application, i.e. also support for either MacOSX 10.4 or MacOSX 10.5.

What would be an easy way to test my build whether it works on PPC?

I thought about [running MacOSX 10.5 in a PPC emulator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/ppc-emulator-to-run-macosx-10-5) but I can't even get PearPC to compile (but that isn't the scope of this question). Is that the easiest way or is there some simpler way to test my builds? How are other people doing it? (Despite just dropping the support for older MacOSX and dropping PPC support.)

Comment: FYI it's not just a case of PPC or not.  Xcode tends to make PPC code that won't run on G3 machines if you're not careful.

Comment: @JWWalker: Can you give some details? How should I be careful?

Comment: If you say `lipo -info path-to-your-binary`, you want it to say that one of the architectures is `ppc`.  If it says `ppc7400`, it won't run on a G3, and you may have to do things like compile with an older version of gcc.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways that come to mind:

1. Find a real PPC Mac.  These go for pretty cheap on eBay.
2. Strip out the x86 sections, using lipo/ditto, keeping only the ppc sections, and run it in Rosetta with 10.6.  Unfortunately 10.7 and later do not support Rosetta.

Comment: You wouldn't need to strip out the x86 code.  Get Info on the app and check "Open using Rosetta".

Comment: I don't have MacOSX 10.6. I am using MacOSX 10.9.

Comment: @Albert, clearly you need 10.6 or earlier.  Depending on your hardware, you might be able to install it on an external drive or virtual machine.